# What to do if I get "Cannot Get" error in webpage?

Tags: html, xcode, npm, browser-sync

I'm creating an HTML file in xcode and trying to display its contents in the browser. I made an empty file and wrote this in:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML is Structure Only (After)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="color: green; font-size: 60px; text-align: center;">HTML is Structure Only</h1>
    <p style="margin: 0 100px 0 100px; font-size: 1.5em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae temporibus esse suscipit nisi ad.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, doloribus eos perspiciatis.</p>
    <footer>
      <hr>
      <p style="text-align: center;"
         onclick="alert('EMAILING US IS USELESS');">
         Tech Support: yeah.right@server-is-down.com
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I `cd`'d into the directory where the file is and ran
`browser-sync start --server --files`. Instead of displaying the file contents in safari it just showed me a `cannot GET /` error page. Help???

I'm on macOS 10.15. The HTML text is not mine, I took it from my lecturer's github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the beginning of the document, before the `<html>`

Comment: Do you have a `.html` file?
Example: `test.html`